# Bash script that exits when user supplies particular input

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to write a script that shows a question to the user: "Are you boring yet? (1=Yes; 2=No)". The script should run until the user hits 2. I am new to Bash and so far I've spent around 6 hours writing this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Are you boring yet ? No = 1 , Yes = 2"
read $1
if [[ $1 -eq 1 ]]
then
echo "Are you boring yet ? No = 1 , Yes = 2"
read $2
if [[ $2 != 2 ]]
then
break
fi
fi
```

But whether I press 1 or 2 it has the same output for closing it.

Any ideas how to make the script correctly?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a while loop and you only need to ask the question once.  As long as you keep pressing 1 it will loop over and over until 2 is pressed, then `break` is called to exit the loop.  Also, just use a name for assigning variables, then use `$name` to call the variable.  I used `junk` for the example.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    echo "Are you bored yet? No = 1, Yes = 2"
    read junk
    if [[ $junk -eq 2 ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: ohhh now I get it.. wow ! Thank you very much for your time and help !